# is there a way to search encrypted data using LIKE?

Tags: database

In a fulltextsearch where the field is encrypted, is there a way to search for its content?

E.g.:
value on the database is name = "John Stewart" (encrypted)
I want to search for either records that contains "John" or "Stewart".

Comment: What database system? And what encryption method (if multiple forms are available in your database system)? I expect the answer is no for all of them, but there might be a surprise waiting. It would usually be a huge technical failing if you could spot "substrings" of one encrypted record inside other encrypted records.

Comment: No, not yet. Because you could then search for `J`, `o`, `h`, `n`, `Jo`, `oh`, etcetera, and thereby decrypt the field. There is an active field of crypto research though which would allow you to encrypt the query too, so that the database has no idea what you're searching for. But that's not practical yet.

Answer (score 1):

If encrypted properly this would be nearly impossible. I'm not aware of any options in MySQL that you could use to encrypt a column like you are suggesting. So you'd need to get all results, decrypt in your application, and check against the decrypted value.

If the value has instead been hashed it would be literally impossible, as the shorter string and the longer string would have completely independent hashes, *and* you wouldn't be able to turn the hash of the longer string back into the string itself to check.